# How can I replace line breaks and paragraph marks in text fields, with spaces, in a flat file?

Tags: sql-server, excel, flat-file

How can I replace line breaks and paragraph marks in text fields, with spaces, in a flat file?

I have a tab-delimited text file that parses fine in Excel and Gammadyne CSV Editor Pro.  However, when I try to import it into SQL Server with the import wizard, it breaks some of the text fields into multiple fields. When I copy the text in those fields from Excel into Word, the incorrect field-breaks turn out to be line breaks within text fields.

So I thought, no problem, I'll just open the text file in Word and do a global replace of line breaks with spaces.

However, when I open the file in Word, the line breaks show up as paragraph marks, and in Notepad++ they show up as [CR][LF].  I can't do a global replace for those, because that's also the end-of row delimiter.

I realize that a possible solution would be to add an extra column on the right, fill it with something that won't appear in the text (e.g, |-|-|), then in Word replace all the paragraph marks with spaces, then replace all the last-column entries (|-|-|) with paragraph marks (or more precisely, using Word's conventions, replace "^t|-|-| " with "^p").  Is that the best I can do?

How can I efficiently get rid of these line breaks or paragraph marks within text fields in my flat file?

(Notice that word, "efficiently").  I've got 15K+ rows and 24 columns, so a one-by-one replacement would not exactly be "efficient"!)

Any suggestions?  Thanks!

Integral

Comment: This sounds like you have your row delimiter as a line break, and you also have unquoted data in your csv file that should be treated as part of the value. Replacing all the line breaks won't solve the issue, as then you get rid of your row delimiters. If you *are* quote identifying your data, make sure you tell the import wizard it is.

Comment: Thanks, Larnu. My fields are tab-delimited, my rows are paragraph-mark-delimited.  My text fields are sometimes quote-enclosed, sometimes not, and sometimes have quote marks within them.  (I didn't create this monster! - and I'll have to deal with its siblings again and again.)  But SQL Server import wizard doesn't treat the paragraph breaks within fields as row breaks, it treats them as field delimiters - until it fills the last available column, then it pushes the remaining data from that row into the next row(s).

Comment: Seems like you've not defined your row and column delimiters properly. Also, you're data **needs** to be well defined. It can't have 1 row with 7 columns, another with 9, and another with 12. They must all have the same number of columns.

Comment: Thanks again, Larnu. The spreadsheet (and many more just like it, soon to come my way) hit my desk as a comma-delimited CSV file, with commas also in text fields. Excel formatted it correctly, but SQL Server broke the fields at every comma, so I changed it to tab-delimited, which  fixed that. So now I'm down to eliminating the paragraph breaks within text within cells - which I'll now try doing as I described in my original post, although I'd prefer a neater solution. Unfortunately, I have no control over how these spreadsheets are formatted when they arrive - I must take them as they are. Thx